# How to access to an URL selector at a component level

Tags: aem

Scenario: (AEM 6.3.2) I'm requesting a page with the selector "test1", like this:
http://localhost:4502/content/myapp/home.test1.html

This page have a parsys where I have drop a component "slider", so the component's path is: "/content/myapp/home/jcr:content/parsys/slider"

**At the "slider" component level, how can I access to the "test1" selector?**

I've tried different ways (SlingModel, WCMUsePojo, the "request" HTL Global Object...), but always get the same problem: the "request" I can access is the GET request of the **component** (GET "/content/myapp/home/jcr:content/parsys/slider.html") where the selector is not present.

Comment: Wich version of AEM do you use?

Comment: Version: AEM 6.3 SP2

Comment: Have you tried https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2336146 ?

Comment: Note: Without any example code we can only guess and this will proberbly only waste time.

Comment: it kinda depends on how you're instigating your component in your home.html's resourceType. Selectors are passed down to child components of a component unless overwritten/changed along the way. If you setup your component via data-sly-include, you basically removed the selector, so either you pass it in at that point or you include via data-sly-resource, which should preserve it, and you should have a file called test1.html in the slider component which will be called directly if the selector was present - which avoids the guessing logic

Comment: As I said in the question, the component is added to the page through a parsys, so I  don't have control on how is the component included. I'll add code samples to clear that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the exact same component/code on another AEM instance (same version) and it's working... will check what can be causing the wrong behavior, but I guess the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the method `SlingHttpServletRequest##getPathInfo` inherited from [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo--)

In your example, if you make a request to:

`http://localhost:4502/content/myapp/home.test1.html`

Then in your component's Class (Use/SlingModel) you can call `request.getPathInfo()` which will return: `/content/myapp/home.test1.html`

Then you can parse that path using: [com.day.cq.commons.PathInfo](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/PathInfo.html)

**Here is an example sling model:**

```
package com.mycom.core.models;
import com.day.cq.commons.PathInfo;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.DefaultInjectionStrategy;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.Self;

@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class,
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class SampleModel {

  @Self
  SlingHttpServletRequest request;

  public PathInfo getPathInfo() {
    return new PathInfo(request.getPathInfo());
  }

}
```

then in your HTML you can do:

```
<sly data-sly-use.sample="com.mycom.core.models.SampleModel"/>
<div>${sample.pathInfo.selectors @ join=', '}</div>
```

An that will output: (based on your example path)

```
<div>test1</div>
```